# Mocking an array of type with Rhino Mock

Tags: mocking, rhino-mocks

I am having issues mocking an array with Rhino Mock, any direction would be great.

```
namespace Checks_Rhino_Mocks
{
    public class Check
    {
        public Header header;
        public Detail[] details;
    }

    public class Header
    {
        public string Number;
        public decimal Amount;
    }

    public class Detail
    {
        public string Id;
    }


    [TestFixture]
    public class CheckUT
    {
        [Test]
        public void CheckShouldHaveMultipleDetails()
        {
            MockRepository mock = new MockRepository();

            Check check = mock.StrictMock<Check>();
            check.header = mock.StrictMock<Header>();
            //issue
            check.details = mock.StrictMock<Detail[]>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: Error 'System.NotSupportedException : Can't create mocks of sealed classes'.  As for using IEnumerable there would be a type cast issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mock Check.details because it's not virtual. RhinoMocks, Moq, etc, can't mock non-virtual methods.

To solve this, make the field virtual:

```
public class Check
{
    public virtual Header header;
    public virtual Detail[] details;
}
```

But...and here's the real point: why are you trying to mock a Detail array? What are you trying to do, exactly? Explain what you're trying to do and we'll be able to really help you.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the check details, you will probably have to do it with IEnumerable:

```
check.details = mock.StrictMock<IEnumerable<Detail>>();
```

instead of an array...

Answer (score 0):

why not just create an array?  is there a reason you want to mock an array?  i'd think you could just use a real array and assert that you have whatever elements (which could be mock instances) in the array you want.  it's hard for me to imagine the test you couldn't do with just a real array.